# need to remove fusionreactor entry from jvm

Tags: java, coldfusion, jvm, fusionreactor

i had Fusion Reactor Installed on my Machine, I unstalled other Day, the Folder for Fusion reactor was still there and I was not able to delete it, I found the JVM config file has still some entries, I want to remove those, What entries from the below should be removed, so i can delete my fusion reactor folder

Thanks

Here is the JVm Config File Code

```
# Arguments to VM
java.args=-server  -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random -javaagent:C:/FusionReactor/instance/cfusion.cf10/fusionreactor.jar=name=cfusion.cf10,address=8088 -agentpath:C:/FusionReactor/instance/cfusion.cf10/frjvmti_x64.dll -Dcoldfusion.classPath={application.home}/lib/updates,{application.home}/lib,{application.home}/lib/axis2,{application.home}/gateway/lib/,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/flex/jars,{application.home}/wwwroot/WEB-INF/cfform/jars
```

Comment: Have you tried remove the obvious arguments `-javaagent:C:/FusionReactor/instance/cfusion.cf10/fusionreactor.jar=name=cfusion.cf10,address=8088` and `-agentpath:C:/FusionReactor/instance/cfusion.cf10/frjvmti_x64.dll`?

Comment: no i did not, because i do not want to mess up the server, i do not what to remove so that is what i am asking for

Answer (score 1):

As @beloidavisja suggested you should remove the `javaagent` and `agentpath` arguments from the `jvm config`. Those are the arguments required for `fusionreactor`. After removing the arguments from the config file make sure to restart ColdFusion server. A restart is required for the changes to take effect. Read this http://docs.intergral.com/display/FR51/Manual+Installation

Comment: Though be sure you **always** make a backup of jvm.config BEFORE making any modifications. Mistakes in the file can prevent the server from starting, so you do not want to be caught without a backup copy.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep a backup and try this again on weekend

Comment: FusionReactor creates a jvm.config.frbak which is the file before FR was installed.  You can switch back to this assuming you didnt make changes to it when FR was installed.